# Android Studio TODO list item points drawables

Tags: android-studio

I use Android Studio version 0.8.14. Whenever I click TODO button to see my list of TODOs I see my TODO items but I also see some of my drawables are listed as shown in the picture below. Is there a particular reason for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an Android Studio bug. Problem disappeared after installing Android Studio 1.0 RC4.